# XSL change value of parameter

Tags: xslt, parameters

Take a look at my XML (simplified):

```
<head>
<body>
<xs:element type="xs:double"/>
</body>
</head>
```

What I want to do is to change value "xs:double" to "doubleOrEmpty" which is my custom type that allows doubles and empty string. Is it possible with use of XSL? If not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can certainly write XSLT to transform

```
<head xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<body>
<xs:element type="xs:double"/>
</body>
</head>
```

to

```
<head xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<body>
<xs:element type="doubleOrEmtpy"/>
</body>
</head>
```

with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body/xs:element/@type[. = 'xs:double']">
  <xsl:attribute name="type">doubleOrEmtpy</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```